# Uploading multiple images on a Form and using action (React-Router-Dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to upload multiple files and send them to my API. However, I can't seem to find a way to have all the files uploaded with an input in the action, when I'm recovering the FormData. Here is the code :

---

**main.jsx** :

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

import {
    createBrowserRouter,
    RouterProvider
} from "react-router-dom";

import App from './routes/App.jsx'

import { postImages } from './api/AppAction.jsx'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/:id",
        element: <App />,
        action: postImages
    }
]);


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
         <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

---

**App.jsx** :

```
import {
    Form
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Form method='POST' encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="images" multiple required/>
                <button>Upload images</button>
            </Form>
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

---

Action function, in **AppAction.jsx** :

```
function postImages({params, request}) {
    return request.formData()
    .then(formData => Object.fromEntries(formData))
    .then(data => {
        return fetch(`${apiBasename}/Folders/${params.id}/Images`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: data
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
    })
}
```

---

So I upload the files in the input, and on button click the Form is submitted. It pass as an action and goes in postImages, in which I recover the formData (to get the images) and try to send it to my API.
In theory, I should get all images data and send them to the API. However, it doesn't work, and i only get the name of the first file when printing "data".

In addition to that, I use Express and Multer to recover the files, and I already tested it with Postman, and it works.

I also tried directly with the formData :

---

**AppAction.jsx** :

```
function postImages({params, request}) {
    return request.formData()
    .then(formData => {
        return fetch(`${apiBasename}/Folders/${params.id}/Images`,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            body: formData
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        })
    })
}
```

---

But it doesn't work too. I was expecting that maybe putting the formData in the body would work, but it doesn't seem to be formatted correctly when I print it in the console.

Also I can't seem to find good answer on the web, most seem to give exemple for base react, without the use of react-router Form.

In case you ask, my API has been tested (thank postman) and is working.

Comment: Have you tried removing `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` from headers? I had an issue when I manually had those headers set. I believe the browser automatically does this for you